# nested loop right triangle java

Tags: java, loops, nested

so I want to create a numerical right triangle in java using a nested loop and I created this:

```
public class nestedloop
{
    public nestedloop()
    {
       loop();   
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       new nestedloop();
    }

    public static void loop()
    {

      System.out.println(" Enter a number ");
      int n= IBIO.inputInt();

      for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }

    }

}
```

However, as you can see, it creates a right triangle formed out of asterisks and I want it to create it through increasing numbers like this:

1

23

456

78910

I'm confused as to what I need to replace the Asterix with. I was thinking it could be another loop but everything I have tried failed miserably.

Comment: You obviously want to put a counter there whose value increases with each print.

Comment: Show what you tried so far (even if it failed)

Answer (score 2):

Just create a counter:

```
public static void loop(){

    System.out.println(" Enter a number ");
    int n= IBIO.inputInt();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.println(++counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im new to coding so I don't have the initiative to use stuff I've learned previously in my codes

Comment: change your `System.out.print` to `System.out.println` and delete the `System.out.println`after the inner for loop...